# Обрезка изображения

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2010

Имеется загруженное изображение (помещённое в `picturebox` или просто в виде объекта `Image` в памяти). Известны его размеры (пусть будет 1000 на 2000). Необходимо его обрезать, например, до 500 на 1000 (просто обрезать, безо всяких выделений области. Вырезать кусок, начиная с верхнего левого угла).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается. Много гуглил, читал `msdn`, но внятного решения не нашёл.

Помогите примерами, кто чем может!

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Cropping Images](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30725/Cropping-Images), если код рабочий, то думаю разберётесь

```
public static Image Crop(this Image image, Rectangle selection)
{
    Bitmap bmp = image as Bitmap;

    // Check if it is a bitmap:
    if (bmp == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("No valid bitmap");

    // Crop the image:
    Bitmap cropBmp = bmp.Clone(selection, bmp.PixelFormat);

    // Release the resources:
    image.Dispose();

    return cropBmp;
}
```

использование:

```
Image.Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 1000));
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Answer (score 3):

метод хорош, но использовать его просто как `image.Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, twp, thp));` нельзя, т. к. в текущий экземпляр результат не запишется. Вот так работает:

```
image = image.Crop(new Rectangle(0, 0, twp, thp));
```