# Как мне сделать распознавание контуров на определённом участке экрана?

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Хочу сделать программу на c#, которая ищет в игре на определённом участке экрана контур наклеек. То есть, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа моя искала в реальном времени контуры наклеек, сама суть в том, что наклеек изначально нет, но затем они появляются и прога должна их заметить и сделать определённое действие.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/812762/220553 Если это "сайт" или что-то такое, то стоит попробовать поискать запросы к серверу и попробовать их повторить.

Comment: Попробуй библиотеку OpenCV, она включает в себя компьютерное зрение. Там можно определять контуры, измерять размеры, отличать картинки друг от друга. В теории ты можешь находить наклейки и даже определять какие именно наклейки там наклеены.

Comment: О ты тоже не один такой, если можешь дай связь

Answer (score 0):

О шедевро трейдинг, попробуй OpenCV, [Ответ тут](https://habr.com/ru/articles/260741/)

1. захват монитора сделай, [Ответ тут](https://studlearn.com/works/details/zakhvat-ekrana-screenshot-na-yazyke-c-240)
2. обрезку полученого изображения, [Ответ тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/130601/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)
3. саму покупку реализуешь вот так [Ответ тут](https://qna.habr.com/q/496224)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)